# Pip doesn't install latest dependencies of my personal application

Tags: python, pip

Hello I have a personal pip repo where I have uploaded 3 version of a personal library. The versions are:

```sh
my-lib-0.1.0
my-lib-1.0.0
my-lib-1.0.1
```

I have another application which uses my-lib as a dependency, defined in the `setup.py` file like:

```py
install_requires = [
    "my-lib",
    # more packages here
]
```

Now installing my app will install latest version of `my-lib` e.g

`pip install --index-url "myprivate-pip-url-index" my-app` will instal version 1.0.1 of my-lib. Verified by doing this:

```sh
pip freeze | grep my-lib
my-lib==1.0.1
```

But supposing I had already a previous version of my-lib installed manually with pip then installing my latest version of my app will not upgrade the version of my already installed lib.

```sh
pip install --index-url "myprivate-pip-url-index" my-lib==0.1.0
pip install --index-url "myprivate-pip-url-index" my-app
pip freeze | grep my-lib
my-lib==0.1.0
```

I was expecting the installation of `my-app` would see that it requires latest version of `my-lib`, and that `my-lib` is not in latest version and move on with updating it. Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something with pip?

pip version: 20.0.2
python version 3.7
Operating system: MacOS

Comment: Have you tried `pip install -U ...`…? Your app only requires *a* version of `my-lib`, you didn't specify any particular minimum version. Since you already have `my-lib` installed, there's no reason for pip to upgrade it.

Comment: Yes Ι did try `pip install -U` didn't work. No I didn't specify minimum version, but either a maximum, so it was my understanding that pip would go ahead and update it. pip list -o sees that the installed version of `my-lib`  is outdated. I don't want to have a fixed version of the dependency, I just want it to be updated with the latest every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default upgrade strategy is [only-if-needed](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-u). To always upgrade use eager upgrade strategy:

```
pip install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy eager
```

You can configure `pip` to always use eager upgrade strategy using [`pip config`](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_config/):

```
pip config set install.upgrade-strategy eager
```

Comment: I answered before seeing your answer. Thank you very much, I thought default was `eager`

Comment: I saw that setting min and max range for my dependency's version, also updates to the latest when using `pip install -U`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to specify `--upgrade-strategy eager` for it to update my dependency to the latest version I thought that was the default behaviour for some kind of reason. Anyways thank you very much.